# Slack: team slack herokuapp.com

Tags: slack-api, slack

I see many 'name team'-slack.herokuapp. invitations (join) to teams. I'm an admin of my team and I want to make such an invitation. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a small web app that automates the invitation process through the slack-api. For our luck somebody has already done that and it's on GitHub: https://github.com/outsideris/slack-invite-automation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Do keep in mind that tools like the one mentioned above use an undocumented, unsupported API that could potentially cease functioning at any time.